# Technical question regarding using the coarea formula to calculate the relation between the $n$-ball's volume and the $(n-1)$-sphere volume

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

We were shown in class this next calculation: (Here, $V_n(RB^n)$ is the volume of an $n$ dimensional ball of radius $R$, likewise $S_{n-1}$ is the surface area of the $n$ dimensional sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$. $rS^{n-1}$ denotes the $n$ dimensional sphere of radius $r$ and integrating $d\textbf{S}$ means a surface integral.)
$$V_n(RB^n)=\int_{RB^n}1dx=\int_0^R\int_{rS^{n-1}}1d\textbf{S}dr=\int_0^R\int_{S^{n-1}}r^{n-1}d\textbf{S}dr=$$$$=\int_0^Rr^{n-1}\int_{S^{n-1}}1d\textbf{S}dr=\int_0^Rr^{n-1}S_{n-1}dr=\frac{R^n}{n}S_{n-1}$$
and finally $V_n=\frac{1}{n}S_{n-1}$ since $V_n(RB^n)=R^nV_n$. My problem is with the 3rd equality. The first is obvious and the second is the coarea formula. I assume the third equality is a result of a change of variables, but since this is taking place in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I'd expect the change of variables to be $x\mapsto rx$ which gives the Jacobian of $r^n$ - not the $r^{n-1}$ we see after the third equality.

It'd be easier for me to assume the teacher had a mistake here, had she not used this result later on in her lectures... So my question is, was she wrong in the change of variables there or am I missing something about surface integrals?

Comment: This wikipedia article on [n-Sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) is highly relevant. Check hyperspherical volume element section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third equality comes from the fact that the map $$f:\quad{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}^n, \quad u\mapsto x:=r\>u$$
($r$ is constant here) multiplies volume elements by its Jacobian $r^n$ but multiplies $(n-1)$-dimensional surface elements by $r^{n-1}$.

While we are at it: The set $B^n:=\{x\in{\mathbb R}^n\ |\ |x|<1\}$ is the ($n$-dimensional) unit ball in ${\mathbb R}^n$. On the other hand its boundary $\{x\in{\mathbb R}^n\ |\ |x|=1\}$ is not the $n$-dimensional unit sphere, but the $(n-1)$-dimensional unit sphere $S^{n-1}$. The latter has an $(n-1)$-dimensional surface area which you might call $\omega(S^{n-1})$ or similar, but certainly not $S_n$. Therefore the proper way to write your formula would be
$${\rm vol}(R\>B^n)={R^n\over n}\omega(S^{n-1})\ .$$

Comment: yeah I noticed the mistake in notation and just edited that in. I know that the boundary of the $n$-ball is a $(n-1)$ manifold but I thought it's still a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and thus the appropriate change of variables would have Jacobian $r^n$. In the calculation above the change of variables takes place before the surface element is "resolved" in order to obtain $\int_{S^{n-1}}d\textbf{S}$ which is replaced by $S_{n-1}$.

Comment: Could you please explain why would the transformation you've mentioned for a change of variables would affect $(n-1)$ surfaces differently than $n$ surfaces? I mean, the change of variables formula is invariant to the dimension of the surface: $\int_{T({\Omega})}f = \int_{\Omega} (f\circ T) | J_T|$

Comment: @Donjim: just because an $n-1$ manifold is imbedded in an $n$ dimensional space doesn't mean its area becomes $n$ dimensional. The map from the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ taking $u\to ru$ only multiplies the $n-1$ dimensions of the sphere, not the $n$ dimensions of the ball contained in the sphere. That is why the volume element is $\mathrm{d}\sigma\;\mathrm{d}r$, you get $n-1$ dimensions in the $\mathrm{d}\sigma$ and one more in $\mathrm{d}r$.

Comment: @robjohn - Basically what you're saying is that because this is a $(n-1)$ manifold I have a parametrization of it and then I would apply the change of variables in $(n-1)$ dimensional space which would result in a surface element of $r^{n-1}$. Am I correct in understanding here?

Comment: @Donjim: it transforms as its dimension when scaled, and $S^{n-1}$ has $n-1$ dimensions. The extra dimension of volume is perpendicular to the surface: its thickness.

Comment: @Donjim: It is the very essence of dimensionality that if ${\mathbb R}^n$ is linearly stretched by a factor $r>0$ then the lengths of smooth curves embedded in ${\mathbb R}^n$ are multiplied by $r$, the areas of $2$-dimensional surfaces embedded in ${\mathbb R}^n$ are multiplied by $r^2$, the $3$-volumes of $3$-dimensional bodies embedded in ${\mathbb R}^n$ are multiplied by $r^3$, and so on. In particular the $(n-1)$-dimensional area of hypersurfaces embedded in ${\mathbb R}^n$ is multiplied by $r^{n-1}$. This is "intuitively obvious", but can be formally proved using the "Gram determinant".

Comment: @Donjim: Think of a small patch, say $1$"$\times1$" on a ball $100$" in radius (in $\mathbb{R}^3$).  If that ball were blown up to $200$" in radius, the patch would be $2$"$\times2$" and have $4\times$ the area. If you were thinking of a chunk of the ball $1$"$\times1$"$\times1$" just under the surface, then that would become $2$"$\times2$"$\times2$" and have $8\times$ the volume.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, if we let $n=3$, the area of a two-sphere is proportional to $r^2$, not $r^3$.  You haven't changed the $dr$ integral, which still goes from $0$ to $R$.

Comment: Indeed, the surface area of the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $4\pi r^2$. (+1)